# Find occurrence of element

Tags: arrays, search

Given an array in which each element differs from its previous element by +1/-1 find the First occurrence (position) of a given (input) element without using Linear search  eg :- Let array = 4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,9,10,11... input - 10 output - 8 ( First occurrence of 10 is at 8th position)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to skip forward in the array by the difference between the target and the current value. So, in your example the target is 10. Start at the first element and see that the difference between 10 (target) and 4 (current value) is 6. Given that any two adjacent values will only differ by one, you know that the first occurrence of 10 must be at least 6 spots further in the array. So jump ahead and repeat the process until you find the first index. Your code might look something like this:

```
int find_first_occurrence(int target, int array[])
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index <= array.count())
    {
        if (array[index] == target)
        {
             return index;
        }
        index += abs(array[index] - target);
    }
    // Returning -1 would indicate that the target is not in the array
    return -1;
 }
```

Comment: If it solved your problem you should accept it as the answer.